# How to debug java application in Eclipse deployed in tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am working on an web application deployed in tomcat, the problem I am facing is neither it is allowing me to add to tomcat server nor it is allowing me to run on debug mode.

[image]

Comment: I have changed the project facet, after that it allow me to debug.

Answer (score 3):

To debug an application running on an external tomcat, set that tomcat to allow remote debugging, e.g. with JVM params like this:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

Then create a new remote "Remote Java Application" debug config, select connection type "Standard (Socket Attach)" and provide host and port (in the example above the port would be 8787).

Answer (score 1):

To run and debug a Java web application in Eclipse, you need to have a dynamic web project. The error message in your screen shot implies you haven't one. Have a look at the excellent tutorials of Lars Vogel:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html